# Polo petrol as first car for a family of 4 to 5 people

Tags: car

I am from India. I want to buy my first car and I do not have any prior experience about cars. I want a good car which is safe and comfortable. I have read that in India, car manufacturers do not care much enough safety. They keep the vehicle light for mileage. 
About the VW Polo, I have read that with dual airbags, the VW Polo is one of the safest cars in it's price range. The parts are german made, the body is tough. 
But on the other hand, people are telling me it's maintenance is very costly, and it's only 3 cylinders. 
This has really got me confused about my choice.

Kindly give your suggestions about same.

Comment: Shopping advice is off-topic here.

Comment: Hello, the focus of this site is maintenance and repair and because buying decisions are often filled with opinion – and because the criteria change quickly as new models come out – questions about choosing a car are off topic. But don't despair, you know your concerns, it sounds like you want a safe car with reasonable operating costs. There are many review sites that will help you find that information. Or, you could edit your question to be about how to find reliable information on maintenance and operating costs. I think that might fly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different people will have different opinions and recommendations about what car to buy. Some people favour safety, other people favour a low-price, other people favour comfort and features.

You need to decide what is most important to you, and go find a car that corresponds to that. If you are concerned about safety, most countries have a government agency that conducts test crashes of cars of every model. If you don't have such in India, [here's a site](http://www.iihs.org/iihs/ratings) for the US crash test ratings.

If you are concerned about comfort, rent a car of the exact same model and drive it for a few days just to see. If you are concerned about maintenance costs, ask a mechanic. Don't ask "people," ask somebody who has actually worked themselves with their own hands on the exact model you want. Don't ask a mechanic that only works on that brand, ask an independent mechanic at a shop where they work on all kinds of cars. Some cars have a complex assembly which makes simple repairs complicated (there are a lot of components to remove in order to access the components you need to replace), whereas other cars have a simple assembly and most components are readily available.

I've never driven or worked on a VW, so I can't comment on that. But [here's a site](https://gearheads.in/forumdisplay.php?219-Polo) of VW Polo enthusiasts in India.